# Creating a multilevel dataframe by clubbing columns with the same name under top level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level

Consider the following input dataframe:

```
        index      |        col_1            |           col_2             |
         1         |        1234             |           4567              |
         2         |        3456             |           9453              |
```

Each column of the dataframe is a series (timeseries), and we want to do some computations that create series of length equal to the input (for example, computing the running mean of the series of last 5 samples (op_1), and of 10 samples (op_2).

Finally, the output should be grouped under the name of the column like shown below:

```
        Output:

                   |        col_1          |          col_2        |
        index      | value   opr_1   opr_2 | value   opr_1   opr_2 |
         1         | 1234     10       1   | 4567     22       13  |
         2         | 3456     18       6   | 9453     21       4   |
```

This should allow me to access each original column's related computation under a single head `col_1`.

Initially, I thought of increasing the level of the input dataframe manually as:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['value']])
```

But, I cannot figure out how to run `apply` on its second level alone (considering that I want to address the column as `df['col_1']['value']` and then to put those values into the dataframe at the same level inside `df['col_1']['op_1']`.

So, the second approach I tried was to create a dataframe for each operation as

```
op_1 = df.apply(lambda x: op_1_func(x, **params))
op_2 = df.apply(lambda x: op_2_func(x, **params))
```

And then merge the three dataframes to create the desired multilevel view.
However, I cannot figure out a way to concat the dataframes to produce the desired output. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def opr1_func(x, y):
    return sum(x) - y


def opr2_func(x, y):
    return np.mean(x) - y


df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], "col2": [6, 8, 12, 14, 16]})
```

Here is one way to do it using Pandas [advanced indexing with hierarchical index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index):

```py
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ["value"]])

for col in ["col1", "col2"]:
    for new_col, func in zip(["opr_1", "opr_2"], [opr1_func, opr2_func]):
        df[(col, new_col)] = df[(col, "value")].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: func(x, 10))

df = df.reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["col1", "col2"], ["value", "opr_1", "opr_2"]]), axis=1
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

   col1              col2
  value opr_1 opr_2 value opr_1 opr_2
0     2   NaN   NaN     6   NaN   NaN
1     4  -4.0  -7.0     8   4.0  -3.0
2     6   0.0  -5.0    12  10.0   0.0
3     8   4.0  -3.0    14  16.0   3.0
4    10   8.0  -1.0    16  20.0   5.0
```

Comment: This is a valid solution when I want to apply the operation row-wise (axis=0). However, I intended to apply the function columnwise (such as a rolling window mean) where, the above method gives an error.

` 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'`

Comment: I have managed to get the desired result by mixing the two approaches in my question. First, I computed separate dataframes for each operation, added a level to each one of them and concatenated all the dataframes together in the end. Please suggest if you have a simpler method to achieve the same, else I could add my version of code to your answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: HI, I've updated my answer to deal with your use case as I understand it (apply functions column wise with rolling window). Feel free to ignore it if you found a more appropriate solution. Cheers.

Comment: This is good! Previously, I did not understand how the indexing was working in multi-level  dataframes. The last edit helped me get it. Thanks!